# How long does a browser able to stream video?

Tags: browser, video-streaming, client-side

Let's take for example, I have mjpeg stream server playing 720p. Do browsers in theory, able to run the stream forever without a refresh?
Ignoring network issues, server performance, just the client itself receiving those stream request.

Comment: Sure.  Why specifically are you asking?

Comment: Just wanted to know if browser has some sort of limit on this. One use case is if i set a web page in kiosk mode and i have a mjpeg stream.

Comment: No, there isn't a hard limit.  You just need to make sure your web application isn't leaking memory.  Though, you'll probably want that kiosk-mode page to refresh periodically anyway, just in case it gets stuck.